# ERROR: Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

```
ERROR: Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.
```

I have imported Flutter sample application `mahtab-ali-fitness_app_ui` which gives me error, anyone knows about it?

Comment: read the error message and do what's said in that

Comment: yes I did,
local.properties file contains sdk location as well as ndk.

`ndk.dir=C\:\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=C\:\\Android\\Sdk`

Comment: Is this android sdk path or flutter sdk ?

Comment: I moved Android SDK folder to another drive, then my problems started; didn't know about local.properties

Answer (score 33):

You need to go inside the **android** folder. And then click on the **local.properties** file.

It contains something like this:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/sunnysaini/Library/Android/sdk
flutter.sdk=/Users/sunnysaini/development/flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
```

And the issue is with  **flutter.sdk** path. You need to replace this path with your **flutter sdk** path.

Comment: thanks for your quick replay, I am checking with it,
my flutter sdk path is `C:/Android/flutter`

Comment: is it the correct path ? if not then replace it with the valid path.

Comment: yes I clone sdk from here `git clone -b master https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git` at location `C:Android`

Comment: I have this error but my sdk location is true and is flutter.sdk=C:\\sdk_flutter\\flutter   and gives error for ' : '

Comment: And can these values in the `local.properties` file really be changed directly in the file? Because I'm having a different problem with the same file, but when I change the values in the file, every time I build again, the values change back to the wrong ones!  Leading me to believe this file is automatically generated, from settings made elsewhere... I dunno where.

Answer (score 9):

If you installed flutter on C:/ drive. Path will be something like this

```
flutter.sdk=C\:\\flutter
```

Don't forget to add \ after the C.

Answer (score 8):

Android > app > build.gradle: it might work if you replace the code written there with this one

`throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")`

Comment: This might be answer of that question. But, explain why you are saying this... how it can help him/her?

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

In your local.properties file located in android folder of your app, add the path to your downloaded flutter folder and make sure to write the path correctly

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I agree mostly on what others have said, this worked for me:

(Windows+Android Studio)

1. Change these lines in the local.properties file from the Project view to update the paths of your sdks(my_app/android/app/local.properties)

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk

flutter.sdk=C\:\\\\src\\flutter
```

*"username" being your own user

2. In Android Studio restart your IDE using the "File>Invalidate Caches/Restart..." option and press "Invalidate and Restart" from the appearing window.

Android Studio will then restart and `build.gradle` file error should be gone.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the error disappeared when opened the flutter project and did a

> flutter pub get

The file created automatically and when opened in android studio everything was fine

Comment: I think best solution, other answers which propose to specify flutter sdk path are not so convenient

Comment: You can do it in when opened as android project also. It is not required to open flutter project

Answer (score 1):

Check your local.properties file, whether the path to flutter.sdk is valid or not. If it is valid, then try to upgrade the flutter plugin and restart your IDE. This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the flutter SDK installed.

in the command line, run:

`flutter doctor -v`

The first line will show the install path.

if you don't have it installed go to the documentation that you can find it here [Flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install)

Answer (score 1):

to to android folder -> local.properties file
add this line

```
flutter.sdk=C\:\\src\\flutter
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in the `local.properties` file.

```
flutter.sdk=C\:\\flutter_sdk\\flutter_windows_1.17.5-stable\\flutter
```

Make sure to add two backward slashes instead of one between each folder name and a backward slash after `C` also.

Answer (score 0):

I had the right path in local.properties and still there was the same problem.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/user/Android/Sdk
```

solved my problem

Comment: Would have really been nice is you had provided more details and explained what and how you did this.

Answer (score 0):

In **local.properties** of your android project, enter your flutter location like that:

```
flutter.sdk=C:\\src\\flutter
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed app/build.gradle as below and solved it.

Before change

```
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('app/key.properties')
```

After change

```
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
```

Answer (score 0):

Go To!

Android > local.properties

Copy your flutter sdk path from your directory and replace here.

or,

Android > app> build.gradle

replace error line with this line

throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

Done!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

just comment it

//throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")

that'll do the trick.