# "A problem occurred configuring root project 'video_player'"

Tags: android, flutter, video-player

I need help with building an Android APK file with Flutter. I keep getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'video_player'.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

Comment: I think its duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175769/error-flutter-sdk-not-found-define-location-with-flutter-sdk-in-the-local-prop

Comment: Nop....this is not SDK Issue I think something is wrong with my plugins but am not sure what exactly is happening

Comment: As far as I can see from the logs it says SDK location not found. If you think its problem of plugins does the app build when the plugins are removed?

Comment: have checked its not SDK problem.. when I remove all my plugins from pub.yaml the project compiles and builds well...so its not SDK issues though the compiler prints that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I found the problem.

It was in the *build.gradle* file of the video-player plugin. I changed the minimum version of the SDK from compileSdkVersion 27 to compileSdkVersion 28 and the problem was solved.